# Reading complex array and vector from TXT file in FORTRAN90

Tags: input, text-files, fortran90, complex-numbers

I'm trying to write a subroutine in a module that I can include in various codes to read data from a given file. I have several codes (numerical algorithms) which will be reading the data from the file.

The file has the following format:

First entry: No. of rows and columns of my array of data (e.g. 720)

First n(=720) entries: entire first row of the matrix A
Second n(=720) entries: entire 2nd row of the matrix A

etc.

Last n(=720) entries: all n entries of vector b

Each entry has two columns, one for the REAL part of the number, the other for the COMPLEX part.

In summary, an example basic input file:

```
  2
    -0.734192049E+00  0.711486186E+01
     0.274492957E+00  0.378855374E+01
     0.248391205E-01  0.412154039E+01
    -0.632557864E+00  0.195397735E+01
     0.289619736E+00  0.895562183E+00
    -0.284756160E+00 -0.892163111E+00
```

where the first entry says its a 2x2 matrix and 2x1 vector
The first 4 lines are the four entries of the matrix A (left column Real, right column Imag.)
The last 2 lines are the two entries of the vector b (left column Real, right column Imag.)
I have written the following code to try and implement this but it simply outputs the wrong results:

```
    n=           2
    A= (  0.0000000    , 1.08420217E-19) (-9.15983229E-16, 3.69024734E+19) ( 1.26116862E-43,  0.0000000    ) (  0.0000000    ,  0.0000000    )
    b= (  0.0000000    , 1.08420217E-19) (  0.0000000    , 1.08420217E-19)
```

With the code:

```
SUBROUTINE matrix_input(n,A,b) 
IMPLICIT NONE 
!
INTEGER, INTENT(OUT)                                  ::n !size of matrix to be read
COMPLEX, DIMENSION(:,:), INTENT(OUT), ALLOCATABLE     ::A !system matrix to be read
COMPLEX, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(OUT), ALLOCATABLE       ::b !RHS b vector to be read
DOUBLE PRECISION                                      ::A_Re,A_Im,b_Re,b_Im !
INTEGER                                               ::i,j
!----------------------------------------------------------   
! Subroutine outputs 'n'=size of matrix, 'A'=system matrix
! 'b'= RHS vector
!matrix194.txt
OPEN (UNIT = 24, FILE = "matrix_input_test.txt", STATUS="OLD", FORM="FORMATTED",     ACTION="READ")

!Read in size of matrix
READ(24,*) n  

ALLOCATE(A(n,n))
ALLOCATE(b(n))

!Read matrix A:
DO i=1,n
   DO j=1,n

    READ(24,*) A_Re, A_Im
    A(i,j)=CMPLX(A_Re,A_Im)

   END DO 
END DO 

!Read RHS vector b:
DO i=((n*n)+1),((n*n)+n)

   READ(24,*) b_Re, b_Im
   b(i)=CMPLX(b_Re,b_Im)

END DO 


CLOSE(UNIT=24)
DEALLOCATE(A,b)
END SUBROUTINE matrix_input
```

**EDIT:** Following HPC Mark's insights, I have edited my code, and this yields the correct result, however if there are any commands which could lead to issues later on down the line (e.g. with very large arrays that I will be using) I would very grateful to hear about them!

```
   SUBROUTINE matrix_input(n,A,b) 
   IMPLICIT NONE 
   !
   INTEGER, INTENT(OUT)                                  ::n !size of matrix to be read
   COMPLEX, DIMENSION(:,:), INTENT(OUT), ALLOCATABLE     ::A !system matrix to be read
   COMPLEX, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(OUT), ALLOCATABLE       ::b !RHS b vector to be read
   !
   COMPLEX, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE                    ::temp,A_temp !temp vector of matrix A
   DOUBLE PRECISION                                      ::A_Re,A_Im,b_Re,b_Im 
   INTEGER                                               ::i,j,k
   !----------------------------------------------------------   
   ! Subroutine outputs 'n'=size of matrix, 'A'=system matrix
   ! 'b'= RHS vector
   !matrix194.txt
   OPEN (UNIT = 24, FILE = "matrix_input_test.txt", STATUS="OLD", FORM="FORMATTED", ACTION="READ")

   !Read in size of matrix
   READ(24,*) n  

   !Allocate arrays/vectors
   ALLOCATE(A(n,n))
   ALLOCATE(b(n))
   ALLOCATE(temp(n*n+n))
   ALLOCATE(A_temp(n*n))

   !Read matrix A & vector b: 
   !16 characters, 9 decimal places, exponent notation, 2 spaces
   DO i=1,(n*n)+n
       READ(24, FMT="(E16.9, 2X, E16.9)") A_Re, A_Im
       temp(i)=CMPLX(A_Re,A_Im)   
   END DO 

   !Select A:
   DO i=1,n*n
      A_temp(i)=temp(i)
   END DO 
   !Reshape
   A=RESHAPE(A_temp, (/n,n/))

   !Select b:
   k=0
   DO i=n*n+1,n*n+n
      k=k+1
      b(k)=temp(i)
   END DO 

   CLOSE(UNIT=24)
   !Do not deallocate A & b otherwise won't return anything properly
   DEALLOCATE(temp, A_temp)
   END SUBROUTINE matrix_input
```

**RESULTS FROM THE EDITED CODE:**

```
    n=           2
    A= (-0.73419207    ,  7.1148620    ) ( 0.27449295    ,  3.7885537    ) ( 0.24839121    ,  4.1215405    ) (-0.63255787    ,  1.9539773    )
    b= ( 0.28961974    , 0.89556217    ) (-0.28475615    ,-0.89216310    )
```

Answer (score 2):

High Performance Mark has already identified the significant issue, some other notes...

- Your format specification in your updated code suggests two spaces in between numbers.  Your example input suggests one - be mindful of the (optional) leading sign on the second number!
- `A` and `b` are allocatable dummy arguments.  That's a widely supported and very useful Fortran 2003 feature.  You are well beyond Fortran 90!  If that is unintentional then you will need to seriously redesign things, otherwise...
- Being beyond Fortran 90 is a good thing - Fortran 95 (which is the minimum level of standard support offered by all current mainstream Fortran compilers - Fortran 90 is practically obsolete) and Fortran 2003 by extension fixed a serious deficiency in Fortran 90 - as of Fortran 95 local allocatable objects are deallocated automatically when the return or end statement of a procedure is executed.  Your deallocate statement at the end is therefore harmless but redundant.
- You read in the components of each complex number into double precision (note a common source code style used for modern Fortran tends to avoid the `DOUBLE PRECISION` type specifier - it is just a synonym for `REAL(KIND(0.0D0))`).  You then store them into default (single precision) complex.  Is that intentional?  If so, its harmless but a little pointless/inconsistent, otherwise if you intended for the real and imaginary components in the output arrays to be stored at higher precision, then you need to change the declaration of the complex arrays appropriately.  All kinds available for `REAL` must be available for `COMPLEX`, so your declaration could be `COMPLEX(KIND(0.0D0))` (typically you would have the kind as a named constant).
- In an input-output list, a complex scalar variable represents two effective items - the real part followed by the imaginary part.  Consequently your double precision variables `A_Re` and `A_Im`, etc., are somewhat superfluous... `READ(24, FMT="(E16.9, 2X, E16.9)") temp(i)` is all that is required.
- Personally I wouldn't bother with the other temporary arrays - once you know the size of the input data (the first line) allocate your `A` and `B` arrays to the necessary size and read directly into them.  In an io list an array is expanded into its elements in array element order (first subscript varies fastest) - which appears to be the way your file is arranged.  You can combine this with what's known as format reversion to eliminate the need for loops.
- Upon return from your subroutine the allocatable arrays "know" their shape - there's no need to return that information separately.  Again, harmless but redundant.

Consequently - I think your entire subroutine could look something like:

```
! Read A and B in from a file that has... etc, etc...
! Assuming a module procedure, where the module already has IMPLICIT NONE.
SUBROUTINE matrix_input(A, b)
  ! Number of rows and columns of A, elements of B.
  INTEGER :: n
  ! Our output data.  
  COMPLEX(KIND(0.0D0)), INTENT(OUT), ALLOCATABLE :: A(:,:), b(:)
  ! Number of the logical unit for IO.  In F2008 this becomes a variable 
  ! and you use the NEWUNIT specifier.
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: unit = 24
  ! The name of the file to read the data from.
  CHARACTER(*), PARAMETER :: filename = "matrix_input_test.txt"
  ! Format for the array and vector component of the data.
  CHARACTER(*), PARAMETER :: fmt = "(E16.9, 1X, E16.9)"
  !*****************************************************************************      
  ! Connect to the file for sequential formatted reading.
  OPEN(unit, FILE=filename, STATUS='OLD', ACTION='READ')
  READ (unit, *) n            ! Get array dimension.
  ALLOCATE(A(n,n), b(n))      ! Allocate result arrays.
  READ (unit, fmt) A          ! Read in A.
  READ (unit, fmt) b          ! Read in B.
  CLOSE (unit)                ! Clean up.
END SUBROUTINE matrix_input
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code confuses me.  `SUBROUTINE matrix_input` declares arrays `A` and `b` to be `allocatable` with `intent(out)`.  Just before the `END SUBROUTINE` statement you go right ahead and deallocate them.  What do you expect the subroutine to return to the calling routine ?

Comment: I should add that I am a bit of a Fortran novice, so you're statement of confusing code is perfectly valid - thank you! That actually helped me with resolving the issue!